# Connect Doctrine to memcached pool

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Perhaps anybody know, how to connect Doctrine to memcached pool, to use it as a cache driver?

I've check official bundle documentation, and lot of another sources, but didn't find any examples of such connection.

Also due to source code,  I could not find any options to use pool, but perhaps I miss something.

Comment: Did you checked this doc : [Caching drivers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers) ?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find any references for pool configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Didn't test, but the following should work:

in app/config/parameters.yml, set/add

```
parameters:
    memcached.servers:
        - { host: 127.0.0.1, port: 11211 }
        - { host: 127.0.0.2, port: 11211 }
```

in app/config/config.yml set/add

```
services:
    memcache:
        # class 'Memcache' or 'Memcached', depending on which PHP module you use
        class: Memcache
        calls:
            - [ addServers, [ %memcached.servers% ]]

    doctrine.cache.memcached:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcachedCache
        calls:
            - [setMemcached, [@memcached]]
```

in app/config/config_prod.yml, set

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.cache.memcached
        query_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.cache.memcached
        result_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.cache.memcached
```

As I said, I can't test it, but this is the combination of several known-to-work techniques.

**UPDATE:** solution updated based on CrazySquirrel's findings.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks lxg for your ideas. I've build right configuration using your ideas. Please find correct service definition below:

application config:

```
result_cache_driver:
        type: service
        id:  doctrine.cache.memcached
```

service.yml

```
memcached:
  class: Memcached
  calls:
      - [ addServers, [ %memcached_servers% ]]

doctrine.cache.memcached:
      class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcachedCache
      calls:
        - [setMemcached, [@memcached]]
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that Doctrine ships an own service implementation for that. Nice to see that it works!

Comment: I took the liberty to update my own post with your findings, so there's one "unified" description.